# State updating one step behind

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update my state value to determine if I should show a filtered list or not. The state value I'm updating is dependent on 3 other state values that are being updated through 3 drop-down lists. Right now, the code is working 1 step behind, changing to false only after I change one more item after it should already be false and vice versa

```
 const [showFiltered, setShowFiltered] = useState(false);
  const [dayFiltered, setDayFiltered] = useState("Filter-by-Day");
  const [shiftFiltered, setShiftFiltered] = useState("Shift-Type");
  const [currentSort, setCurrentSort] = useState("Sort");


const searchAndFilter = (day, shiftType, sort) => {
    setDayFiltered(day);
    setShiftFiltered(shiftType);
    setCurrentSort(sort);
    showFilteredList();
  };

  const showFilteredList = () => {
    dayFiltered !== "Filter-by-Day" ||
    shiftFiltered !== "Shift-Type" ||
    currentSort !== "Sort"
      ? setShowFiltered(true)
      : setShowFiltered(false);
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: I think my biggest issue is that the showFiltered is dependent on 3 different states, I was thinking about using the useEffect() but didnt know if it was possible to have more than 1 state dependency

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `showFiltered` depends solely on other state, then it is redundant state and should simply be a regular variable. This makes the `showFilteredList` function also unnecessary.

```js
const [dayFiltered, setDayFiltered] = useState("Filter-by-Day");
const [shiftFiltered, setShiftFiltered] = useState("Shift-Type");
const [currentSort, setCurrentSort] = useState("Sort");
const showFiltered =  dayFiltered !== "Filter-by-Day" ||
    shiftFiltered !== "Shift-Type" ||
    currentSort !== "Sort";
```